# How to build a C# project when needed in vscode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, I can run a C# project without debugging and without building if not needed.

In Visual Studio Code, However, I couldn't find any way to do this.
If I run without debugging, it always builds because of the "preLaunchTask": "build" configuration in launch.json.

I also commented out the preLaunchTask, but then the build itself does not work.

Is there any solution to do this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: why not just start it from commandline?

Comment: Even if I use the command line, I can't do the exact same as the Visual Studio. 'dotnet run --no-build' doesn't build even when source files are modified. What I want to do is check, before running, if files have changed and if so, build in advance.

Comment: how about use `./thebinary` when no change, `dotnet run` when code changes?